# uibModal doesn't appear on full screen angularjs html5

Tags: angularjs, html, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a uibModal with angularjs 1.6 but my modal always not appear on full screen section.

What can be the problem?[image]

Comment: Please post your markup or JS so we can understand your situation, based on the background gradient it looks like your modal is rendering inside another container that might be restricting the size.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a uibModal implementation.

A controller function that opens a modal with the specified size. Options are 'lg' 'md' 'sm'. Look at your html template for containers restricting the modal size.

https://plnkr.co/edit/IjAdQg9kt8mdMSeDOFsk?p=preview

The Controller:

```
$scope.open = function () {
  $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    size: 'lg'
  });

  $scope.modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
   console.log(result);
  }, function(err) {console.log(err);});
 };
});
```

Simple HTML Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
   <p>body content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
   <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</script>
```